# utf8 inputenc error (RStudio & knitr & pdflatex); unknown unicode character 150=U+0096

Tags: unicode, utf-8, knitr, pdflatex

I originally ran my .Rnw-file with the latex option:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

It produced an error:

"! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX."

I switched to `[utf8x]`, which generated a somewhat more helpful error message:

"! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 150 = U+0096,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-0.def."

I tried to replace the 0096 (http://www.charbase.com/0096-unicode-start-of-guarded-area) character with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0096}{\"o}` to easily detect where to problem was but when using `[utf8x]` the error message remained the same and when using `[utf8]` there was an additional error: "! Package inputenc Error: Cannot define Unicode char value < 00A0"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my bibliography. In my editor (TeXstudio), the character U+0096 is rendered as whitespace. For some unknown reason, the line pdflatex reports as containing the offending character is inaccurate.

I solved the problem by running a regular expression search for `\x0096` and it found the offending character immediately. Deleting the character and replacing it with a true space fixed the issue.

Incidentally, I tried the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0096}{ }` fix and it did nothing for me. This could be because the offending character was in the .bib file rather than the .tex file where I placed the command.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is workable way by switching the [utf8x]. 
Just carefully check your code, particularly the part you copy from somewhere, not type it by your self.

I do have the same problem recently.

I show you How I solve this problem.

I remove the code from the R markdown part by part to find which part caused this problem. Finally, I found the below part that resulted in the error in my code.

```
### Platform：Affymetrix A-AFFY-2-Affymetrix GeneChip Arabidopsis Genome [ATH1-121501].
```

I remember I copy this information from webpage. So I delete them and type this part by myself. It can run and generate the pdf file without any error.

To be clear, I show you the difference between the copy version and the version of my typing:

[image]

This is just one example I think. I want to point out that it is always problematic when you copy something from an unknown resource file into your code.

Hope this can help you and other people who were frustrated by this problem.